# dependency injection and ado.net and asp.net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection

I have been learning DI and i have implemented something but i want to be sure if my implementation meets or not the DI rules:

an interface with a signiture :

```
 public interface IDashboardRepository
{

   public object sumAndAVG(string regionalManager, string dtFrom, string dtTo);
}
```

a class to implement the interface signature :

```
        public class DashboardRepo:IDashboardRepository
        {

            private string cn = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyDB"].ConnectionString;
            NpgsqlConnection con = null;
            public object sumAndAVG(string regionalManager, string dtFrom, string dtTo)
            {
                DataTable dt_sumProAval = new DataTable();
                NpgsqlDataAdapter SumOfProduction = new NpgsqlDataAdapter(@"TheSQL is here since its long not part of the topic i removed it", cn);
                SumOfProduction.Fill(dt_production);
                var sumAndAvail = (from DataRow dr in dt_production.Rows
                                   select new AverageSumViewModel

                                   {
                                      avg = Convert.ToDouble(dr["avalability"] == DBNull.Value ? 0.0 : dr["avalability"]),
                                   }).ToList();

                return sumAndAvail;
            }
        }
```

At the end in my controller i use it like:

```
  _idashboard.sumAndAVG( regionalManager,  dtFrom,  dtTo);
```

please tell me if im in a right direction

Comment: This isn't the place to ask such a broad question. Having said that, you're not doing DI here, since you are `new`ing up all your objects, there's no injection happening at all.

Comment: @DavidG you mean in my Controller?what should i do then if i dont new anything how can i access the class?

Comment: The last snippet of code you show, that's not following the DI pattern. The IoC container should be responsible for creating the objects.

Comment: @DavidG i edit my controller(last part of my code)now is it better?

Comment: Slightly OT: are you really returning an `object` instead of `List<AverageSumViewModel>`?

Comment: @HansKeﬆing yes

Comment: Any particular reason? Returning a plain object means you have to remember to cast to the correct type to use it.

Comment: @HansKeﬆing not really,actually i return datatable,since the focus of the question is on DI,i did not care  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I understand about Dependency Injection and Inversion of Control:

> "Dependency Injection, in simple terms, is the implementation to an
>   IOC pattern.Instead of tight coupling the dependency of one object into
>   another using the 'new' keyword, pass it as an external dependency
>   using constructor/property/method injection".

For detailed insight, read here - https://martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html

Coming to your question, you have implemented the pattern using constructor injection in your code

**Interface**:

```
public interface IDashboardRepository
{

   public object sumAndAVG(string regionalManager, string dtFrom, string dtTo);
}
```

**Implementation:**

```
public class DashboardRepo:IDashboardRepository
{
    //Simplified for understanding
}
```

**Usage of IDashboardRepository into another object:**

```
public class DashboradHandeler
{
  public  IDashboardRepository _idashboard;

  public DashboradHandeler(IDashboardRepository _idashboard)
  {

      this._idashboard = _idashboard;
  }
}
```

**Usage of DashboradHandeler in another object (your controller):**

```
DashboradHandeler dashboard = new DashboradHandeler(new DashboardRepo());
        dashboard._idashboard.sumAndAVG(regionalManager,dtFrom,dtTo);
```

**Observations**:

1. Injection of *IDashboardRepository* into *DashboradHandeler* class is
   loosely coupled. It inverts the responsibility of object creation of
   *IDashboardRepository* class from *DashboradHandeler* to the caller. In
   your case, it is *DashboradHandeler*.

   However, the instantiation of
   DashboradHandeler class can be modified. Instead of doing: `DashboradHandeler dashboard = new DashboradHandeler(new DashboardRepo());` , you can invert the object creation to an external container like Autofac, Ninject. Avoid using the 'new' keyword wherever applicable.
2. Naming conventions can be improved. '_' notation is used primarly with private properties. Use one of them not both:

**Your code**:

```
    public class DashboradHandeler
    {
      public  IDashboardRepository _idashboard;

      public DashboradHandeler(IDashboardRepository _idashboard)
      {
          this._idashboard = _idashboard;
      }
    }
```

**With '_' notation**:

```
public class DashboradHandeler
    {
      private IDashboardRepository _idashboard;

      public DashboradHandeler(IDashboardRepository idashboard)
      {

          _idashboard = idashboard;
      }
    }
```

**Without '_' notation**:

```
public class DashboradHandeler
    {
      private IDashboardRepository idashboard;

      public DashboradHandeler(IDashboardRepository idashboard)
      {

          this.idashboard = idashboard;
      }
    }
```

These are few points I can think of right now.

Comment: Thanks a lot,but if i remove the dashboardHandler class,and use it directly in my controller(the constructor) without creating NEW,why i should use Ninject?

Comment: How are you going to provide the dependecy of that object in your controller? You’ll require a container to provide the concrete implementations to your dependencies. Constructor Injection is a way to invert the dependeny creation but still you need someone to perform the job to create these dependencies.

Comment: @sorry Sahil but what do you mean by  dependecy of that object ?

Comment: I mean the actual instance of DashboardHandler class in your controller.

Comment: I have removed the DashboardHandler  and i wrote my constructor directly in my  controller as you see in the edited code

Comment: Try to run the project. You’ll get NullReferenceObject error. If you need some reference with this pattern, I have a Github project created, try this link - https://github.com/iSahilSharma/NewEmployeeBuddy.API/blob/master/NewEmployeeBuddy.Facade/Controllers/Employee/EmployeeController.cs

Comment: No parameterless constructor defined for this object...is it?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, you don´t need your `DashboradHandeler` - you can inject the interface to the specific controller in its own constructor. Furthermore you are using `new`, which is not what DI wants you to do ;)

Doing so, you always have the interfaces you need just within your controller.

Think of dozens / hundreds of controllers, that use `DashboradHandeler`: you will not be able to know all of the interfaces used in `DashboradHandeler`. And all of your controllers would strongly depend on that class ...

Comment: can you write here what should i write instead of creating new?

Comment: yep, please see my answer below.

Comment: Please don't post multiple answers, just [edit] this one.

Answer (score 0):

You're close, but think you want to set it up more like this:

```
public class DashboradHandeler
{
  private readonly IDashboardRepository _idashboard;

  public DashboradHandeler(IDashboardRepository idashboard)
  {

      this._idashboard = idashboard;
  }

}
```

Then use it something like this.  I'm wrapping the injected class' method here for illustration purposes, not because it's required.  This is not really an ideal way to do DI, but should help you out.

```
DashboradHandeler dashboard = new DashboradHandeler(new DashboardRepo());
dashboard.sumAndAVG(regionalManager,dtFrom,dtTo);

// This is in your DashboradHandeler class
public object sumAndAVG(string regionalManager, string dtFrom, string dtTo)
  {
     _idashboard(sumAndAVG(regionalManager,dtFrom,dtTo));
  }
```

Comment: thanks,but create New Dashboard is meaning i still not satisfying the DI?

Comment: This still isn't DI

Comment: @DavidG...Why do you say that?  The dependency is being injected.  There's still a long way to go, but there is DI here.

Comment: No, you're still manually creating the object (e.g. `new Foo(new Bar)`) but for DI those objects need to be created by something else, so usually a container.

Comment: @DavidG...I see that,too.  But there is DI for DashboradHandeler's dependency.  A container is never a requirement, although I always use one :)

Comment: @mrslt...please see my comments to DavidG.  You're not 100% DI, but you are in regards to DashboradHandeler's dependency

Comment: @BigDaddy how do you make this example DI?

Comment: @mrslt...It is DI, just not all the way.  What I've posted is DI.  A point has been made about it not being DI because you're newing-up DashboradHandeler and it's true - that part is not.  If you follow my pattern and inject DashboradHandeler where it's used, you'll have even more DI.  You need to end in a place where you don't new anything up.  The fastest way to get there is with a DI container like Unity, Ninject, etc

Answer (score 0):

See this example:

your controller

```
public IGetService iGetService { get; set; }

public HomeController() { }

public HomeController(IGetService iGetService)
{
     this.iGetService = iGetService;
}
```

Now, if any action in your controller wants to invoke a method from that interface, you just do something like the following:

```
public void MyAction()
{
    var myVar = iGetService.GetAllFromDataBase();
}
```

Comment: I have edited my question according to what you said,can you see it please?

Comment: remove the empty default constructor.  If you are using DI, there is no use for it.

Comment: Ninject said, I needed a default one. If I remove that, Ninject throws an exception saying that no default constructor was defined. So I just put that code line into my controllers.

Comment: I think you´re heading the right direction,  mrslt.

Comment: @WhoMightThisOneBe if you are getting that error from Ninject, then you haven't setup the container correctly.

Comment: I just followed the tutorials. But honestly, I don´t care: Leave that line of code right where it is, it´s no harm to anyone :)